# textfiled is not empty when i return from log-out to log in screen [ SWIFT ]

Tags: ios, swift

Hope i did all work for login and log out.But when i try to logout its working fine.but when i return to login screen my username/password are remain there.

**Needed**

How to do when i logout or return to my login screen my text field should empty.

Here is my VC.swift

```
struct storyboard {
    static let ShowLoginSegue = "sss"
}

@IBOutlet weak var userField: UITextField!


@IBOutlet weak var passField: UITextField!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.userField.delegate = self
    self.passField.delegate = self
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@IBAction func loginBut(sender: AnyObject) {
    
    
    
 let klak = ""
    let qwqw = ""
    
    if userField.text == klak && passField.text == qwqw
    {
        
        print("correct")
          performSegueWithIdentifier(storyboard.ShowLoginSegue, sender: nil)
        
    }
    else
    {
        
        print("wrong")
    }
```

}

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Where are you storing your login information? When you logout you need to delete that information and when you load the login screen it should be deleted, too.

Comment: you can simply clear the textfields right before you perform segue!!!

Comment: i din store any where my username/password.i used some var to store..is the ways correct or any other way to save my username/password

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this code to your VC.swift

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        userField.text = ""
        passField.text = ""

    }
```

Try out & let me know !

Comment: Thanks will check out

Comment: func viewWillAppear is a method in swift. This method is called before the view controller's view is about to be added to a view hierarchy and before any animations are configured for showing the view. You can override this method to perform custom tasks associated with displaying the view. For example, you might use this method to change the orientation or style of the status bar to coordinate with the orientation or style of the view being presented. If you override this method, you must call super at some point in your implementation.

Comment: Docs here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621510-viewwillappear